# How to Autheticate Azure Api from an Asp.Net Core app using Current logged in User

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-fluent-api

I have an App hosted in Azure using Azure AD Authentication.
I want the the current logged in user to be used to be used to manage Azure resources. I want this to be simple for the user. If the Signed In account is an Azure management account, I want to use his Identity (the Current User) to manage Azure resources. This app will be used to check Azure Resource existence and permissions. The current user should have the required privileges in AD.

I know the following is wrong, but I think it conveys what I want to do.
Something like this:  **(User.Identity is the Asp.Net user)**

```
public class ConfigurationModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
        var azure = Azure.Configure()
           .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.BodyAndHeaders)
>>>           .Authenticate(User.Identity)
           .WithSubscription("...");;

        var resources  = azure.ResourceGroups.List()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the current time this may not be possible... [Azure App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) states that "At this time, ASP.NET Core does not currently support populating the current user with the Authentication/Authorization feature." Click on the link to the right to see for yourself... [Azure Warning Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Ex2.png)